# How to merge multiple arrays in pairs with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I get values from a table in a form. I have 2 rows and 2 colums.
Each column has 2 values.

I manage to get columns values by rows, I have this array :

```
array (
  // 1st row
  0 => array (
      0 => 30,
      1 => 34,
      2 => 50,
      3 => 52
  ),
  // 2nd row
  1 => array (
      0 => 34,
      1 => 38,
      2 => 52,
      3 => 54
  )
)
```

Expected output :

```
array (
  // 1st row
  0 => array (
      // 1st col
      0 => array (
          0 => 30,
          1 => 34
      ),
      // 2nd col
      1 => array (
          0 => 50,
          1 => 52
      )
  ),
  // 2nd row
  1 => array (
      // 1st col
      0 => array (
          0 => 34,
          1 => 38
      ),
      // 2nd col
      1 => array (
          0 => 52,
          1 => 54
      )
  )
)
```

I would like to explode each row array in 2 pairs (= 2 colums with 2 values for each one).

I don't know how to do this, maybe with a `for` loop or with modulus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a loop on your array and use array_chunk on each row :

```
$array = array (
    array (30,34,50,52),
    array (34,38,52,54)
);

foreach ( $array as &$row ){
    $row = array_chunk($row, 2);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

use array_map, and array_chunk

```
array_map(function($v){return array_chunk($v, 2);), $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [array_chunk](http://php.net/array_chunk):

```
$array = array (
  // 1st row
  0 => array (
      0 => 30,
      1 => 34,
      2 => 50,
      3 => 52
  ),
  // 2nd row
  1 => array (
      0 => 34,
      1 => 38,
      2 => 52,
      3 => 54
  )
);

foreach ($array as &$a) {
    $a = array_chunk($a, 2);
}

print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 30
                    [1] => 34
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 50
                    [1] => 52
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 34
                    [1] => 38
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 52
                    [1] => 54
                )

        )

)
```